# OpenGL rotate car towards circular path

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 2d, webgl

I have a problem regarding the "steering" of an object towards a circular path.

I have written a small animation where a 2D car (top-down-view) drives in a roundabout. Currently it looks like the car is drifting in the roundabout.

**My question is:** How do I rotate the car around its center so that it looks like it's steering towards the circular roundabout path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, calculate in update method first this:

```
var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
```

btw. p2.x and p2.y will be center point (so car is p1). And now on your p1.z position add to update method for object this:

```
p1.rotation.z = angleRadians;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately the car is now rapidly rotating around its center the whole time. Did I understand it correctly, that p2 is the center of the whole animation?

Comment: yeah p2 is your center point, btw this `var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x); ` have to calculate on every frame in update too

Comment: so what, helped it?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I did it exactly like you told me to, but it didn't help. The car just rotates around its center the whole time.

Comment: My guess is that I somehow have to synchronize the "steering" with the translation along the circular path. The only way I got in mind is to multiply the angle with the time-delta of the last animation and the current one.

Comment: Have you always actual position of car and actual position of that center object? Can you give me somehow your code to look at it and try solve it? If yeah my email is heckowork@gmail.com or fiddle or something

Comment: I just solved the problem. Made a stupid mistake. Just forgot to actually calculate the time delta of the animations.

Comment: Thanks for your great help!

Comment: You are welcome :)